# Calling BeginRead from a NetworkStream

Tags: c#, network-programming, networkstream

Ok I want to connect to a `Socket` and read a network stream using the `System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream` class. This is what I have so far:

```
NetworkStream myNetworkStream;
Socket socket;

socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, 
    ProtocolType.IPv4);
socket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8"), 8888);

myNetworkStream = new NetworkStream(socket);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int offset = 0;
int count = 1024;

myNetworkStream.BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, ??, ??);
```

Now I need an `AsyncCallback` and an `Object state` to complete my `BeginRead` method but I'm not even sure if this is going to work. I'm a bit lost at this point! Where do I need to go from here?

Comment: You are on the wrong track.  Use the MSDN Library example code for Socket.BeginReceive().

Comment: Do you have a reason to use the async version? Can't you just use `Read()`?

Comment: Would that work? Eventually I want to have this a service that runs constantly but for now I just want to see some results. Also, thank you Hans, I will check it out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically, when you call the `Begin*` method on an asynchronous operation, there needs to be a call to a corresponding `End*` statement (for more detailed information, see the [Asynchronous Programming Overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx), specifically the section titled "Ending an Asynchronous Operation").

That said, you generally want to pass a method/anonymous method/lambda expression which will do one or two things:

1) Call the corresponding `End*` method, in this case, [`Stream.EndRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.endread.aspx).  This call will not block when called because the `callback` will not be called until the operation is complete (note that if an exception occurred during the async call then this exception will be thrown when the `End*` method is called).

2) Possibly start a new asynchronous call.  In this case, it's assumed you'll want to read more data, so you should start a new call to [`Stream.BeginRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.beginread.aspx)

Assuming you want to do #2, you can do the following:

```
// Declare the callback.  Need to do that so that
// the closure captures it.
AsyncCallback callback = null;

// Assign the callback.
callback = ar => { 
    // Call EndRead.
    int bytesRead = myNetworkStream.EndRead(ar);

    // Process the bytes here.


    // Determine if you want to read again.  If not, return.
    if (!notMoreToRead) return;

    // Read again.  This callback will be called again.
    myNetworkStream.BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, callback, null);
};

// Trigger the initial read.
myNetworkStream.BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, callback, null);
```

However, if you are using .NET 4.0, this becomes much easier using the [`FromAsync` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321404.aspx) on the [`TaskFactory` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321401.aspx).

Comment: Alternatively if you are using .NET Framework 4.5+ or .NET Standard/Core you can use [Stream.ReadAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.readasync?view=netframework-4.7.1) within an `async` method